# Al hacer click en un Hipervinculo ejecute codigo php

Tags: php, mysql, filtro

Estoy haciendo una tienda online la cual tiene algunos filtros por categorias ejemplos niñios/niñas. La idea es activarlos con un enlace a href.
La pagina es https://valentinaconfecciones.com/

En el html general tengo todos los productos que voy mostrando de uno a uno los datos estan almacenados en un array que traje de mysql y por cada fila tiene un articulo, en las columnas hay distintos datos como la categoria si es de niño o niña por ejemplo. Este array se va mostrando con un while.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click en e enlace href, en vez de mostrar todos los articulos, se vean solo los que cumplen la condicion elegida por ejemplo los de niño, esto lo hago con otro while que recorre el arreglo antes dicho y va formando otro arreglo a medida que los articulos cumplen la condicion.

Ahora bien como hago para que ese codigo php que redimisiona el arreglo se ejecute al hacer click en el enlace de la categoria de niño, por ejemplo.

En conclusion, que al hacer click en el enlace a href, cambie el arreglo orginal por el otro en el que estan las filas filtradas.

Adjunto parte del codigo php,

Desde ya muchas gracias,

Este es el codigo que muestra todos los articulos originalmente:

```
introducir el código aquí
<section class="products-list">
        <?php 
        $i=0;
        while ($i<$c) {
            echo '<div class="product-item">';
                echo '<img class="img_art" src="' . $array_art[$i][2] . '">';
                     if ($array_art[$i][3]<>0){
                        echo '<div class="img_detalles">';
                        echo '<img src="' . $array_art[$i][4] . '">';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    echo '<div class="more">';
                        echo '<p> Ver colores y talles </p>';
                     echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="art">';
                    echo '<a class="articulo" href="#' . $array_art[$i][0] . '" data-toggle="modal" >';
                        echo "<span>" . $array_art[$i][0] .  "</br></span>";
                        echo "<span>" . $array_art[$i][1] .  "</br></span>";
                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar parámetros por `href` lo que tienes que hacer es concatenarlos al final de la url, se comienza con un signo `?` y entre cada parámetro se pone un`&`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=1">Ropa niño<a/>
<a href="https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=2">Ropa niño<a/>
```

Después en php lo lees con:

`$tipo_ropa = $_GET['tipo'];`

Y tomas las decisiones quie necesites de forma habitual:

```
if ($tipo_ropa==='1') {
   // muestro niño
   ....
} elsif ($tipo_ropa==='2') {
  // muestro niña
  .....
} else {
  // muestro todo
  .....
}
```

Esta es una manera muy limitada de pasar parámetros, pues si quieres hacer combinaciones de varios tendrías que hacer un enlace para cada una:

```
<a href="https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=1&talla=xs">Ropa niño talla xs<a/>
<a href="https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=1&talla=s">Ropa niño talla s<a/>
<a href="https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=2&talla=xs">Ropa niña talla xs<a/>
<a href="https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=21&talla=s">Ropa niña talla s<a/>
```

Lo habitual es hacer un formulario con el filtrado, añadiendo los elementos necesarios para que el usuario escoja cualquier combinación:

```
<form>
<label>Tipo:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_ropa" value="0" checked \>Todos
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_ropa" value="1" \>Niño
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_ropa" value="2" \>Niña
<br/>
<label>Talla:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="talla" value="" checked \>Todos
   <input type="radio" name="talla" value="XS" \>XS
   <input type="radio" name="talla" value="S" \>S
<br>
<button type="submit" name="filtrar">BUSCAR</button>
</form>
```

Con esto se lanzaría una url similar a la usada en los enlaces anteriores, por ejemplo sería:`https://valentinaconfecciones.com?tipo=2&talla=`

Puedes indicar que script quieres que recepciones el formulario mediante el atributo `action` y el método de envío (GET o POST) mediante `method`, por ejemplo: `<form action="/index.php" method="get">`

Más información sobre formularios: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, fue muy clara y lo entendi, pero yo tengo dos tipos de filtros del tipo Niño/Niña y del tipo pantalones, camperas, buzos etc y para activarlos el cliente quiere botones no checkbox o radio, puedo hacer eso mismo con muchos botones? uno para cada categoria?

Comment: Si necesitas que se vean como botones seguro que puedes encontrar algún tutorial para modificar el aspecto del html estándar, por ejemplo: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Zl6ql

Comment: Gracias! Fly por tu ayuda!

Comment: Date una vuelta por el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), para ir aprendiendo como funciona este sitio ;)  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Disculpa una ultima preguntita, como hago para que el filtro se active al activar el input radio, solamente sin utilizar el boton de envio de formulario, como los input van a verse como botones no necesito el boton submit

Comment: Deberías hacer otra pregunta, en los comentarios no se deben poner preguntas ni respuestas. Creo que no diste esa vuelta por el  [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) ;)